# Tweepy Wait on Rate Limit Not Working in Tweepy Streams

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am Trying to Build a Twitter Bot which Streams Tweets Based on List of Given KeyWords.

While Setting Up Auth with Twitter I have specified both `wait_on_rate_limit` and `wait_on_rate_limit_notify` to be **True** as mentioned in Below Code.

`tweepy.API(self.auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)`

But When Starting a Stream from Tweepy with this Auth Credentials it is resetting the values of both `wait_on_rate_limit` and `wait_on_rate_limit_notify` to **False**.

```
print(f'Twitter API Client Retry and Wait :',api.api.wait_on_rate_limit)
print(f'Streaming Class Retry and Wait :',myStreamListener.api.wait_on_rate_limit)
print(f'Stream Object Retry and Wait :',myStream.api.wait_on_rate_limit)
```

`Twitter API Client Retry and Wait : True
Streaming Class Retry and Wait : False
Stream Object Retry and Wait : False`

How can I Set These Options from Tweepy.stream to True?

**Full Code:**

```
#import re 
import tweepy 
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
#from textblob import TextBlob 

# creating object of TwitterClient Class 
class TwitterClient(object): 
    ''' 
    Generic Twitter Class 
    '''
    def __init__(self): 
        ''' 
        Class constructor or initialization method. 
        '''
        # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console 
        consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

        # attempt authentication 
        try: 
            # create OAuthHandler object 
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
            # set access token and secret 
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
            # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets 
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                         wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True) 
        except: 
            print("Error: Authentication Failed") 

# Streaming Class
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.user.screen_name)
        print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
        print(status.text)
        print('--------------------------------------------------------------')

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)



# Twitter Client API Auth
api = TwitterClient() 

# Initialize Streaming Object
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()

# Establish a Stream With API and Streaming Object
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth,tweet_mode="extended",
                         include_rts=False ,listener=myStreamListener)     

# Stream Tweets Based on Key Words
myStream.filter(track=['CAA NRC India'], is_async=True)

print(f'Twitter API Client Retry and Wait :',api.api.wait_on_rate_limit)
print(f'Streaming Class Retry and Wait :',myStreamListener.api.wait_on_rate_limit)
print(f'Stream Object Retry and Wait :',myStream.api.wait_on_rate_limit)

myStream.running = False
```

`Twitter API Client Retry and Wait : True
Streaming Class Retry and Wait : False
Stream Object Retry and Wait : False`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L33

In your case: `myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(api=api.api)` (It is really confusing how you are calling your `TwitterClient` instance `api`.)

For the Stream I don't have something since it seems to always create a new `API()` instance: 
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L235
You can overwrite it with `myStream.api = api.api`

I'm curious however how you are running into rate limiting problems when streaming. This shouldn't happen. It's not an endpoint you manually call repeatedly.

Comment: I was able to Overwrite it as per your Suggestion and it Worked as I Intended.

`
Streaming Class Retry and Wait : True
Stream Object Retry and Wait : True
`

I was trying to implement it because I used the same with `tweepy.cursor` so I thought it is required in `tweepy.stream` too. After a Lot of Research, reading through Twitter API documents and Various other Posts I See that It is Not Required from Stream to Specify Rate Limits.